# Неожиданное поведение элементов при использовании float

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, float

Ну совсем непонятное явление. Не помог ни Гугл, ни игра с CSS-свойствами. Прошу помощи здесь.

На странице два блока - левая колонка (`float:left`) и правая (основное содержимое).
Так вот, если в **правой колонке** использовать для какого-либо элемента свойство `float:left`, и даже после этого очистить `float` (`clear:left` или `clear:both`), то последующие **неплавающие** элементы внезапно выравниваются *по уровню левой колонки*, которая никакого отношения к правой колонки не имеет.

```css
.wrapper {
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left-bar {
 float: left;
 width:200px;
 height: 400px;
 background: red;
}
.right-bar {
 height: 700px;
 margin-left: 210px;
 background: #adc6e7;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-bar">
    <p>Левая колонка</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-bar">
    <img style="float:left;" src="https://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/2017/03/19/2245758/tn/06-funny-cat-wallpapercat-wallpaper.jpg" width=410 />
    <div style="margin-left:420px;">
      <p>Строчка 1</p>
      <p>Строчка 2</p>
    </div>
    <p style="clear:left;">&nbsp;</p>
    <h2>Абзац</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже правильно сказали, вложенность не имеет значения. На вскидку, единственное что могу предложить `overflow: hidden;` для правого блока (что бы вложенные элементы не обращали внимание на то, что находится вне родителя), если это приемлемо ...

```css
.wrapper {
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left-bar {
 float: left;
 width:200px;
 height: 400px;
 background: red;
}
.right-bar {
 height: 700px;
 margin-left: 210px;
 background: #adc6e7;
 overflow: hidden; // Собственно "трикс" ...
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-bar">
    <p>Левая колонка</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-bar">
    <img style="float:left;" src="https://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/2017/03/19/2245758/tn/06-funny-cat-wallpapercat-wallpaper.jpg" width=410 />
    <div style="margin-left:420px;">
      <p>Строчка 1</p>
      <p>Строчка 2</p>
    </div>
    <p style="clear:left;">&nbsp;</p>
    <h2>Абзац</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую использовать. У меня лишь примитивный пример, проект реализован намного сложнее, но другого выхода просто нет!

Answer (score 2):

`clear: left` Это правило гарантирует, что все элементы, к которому применено свойство, будут смещены ниже **ВСЕХ** перемещаемых влево элементов.

Так как у нас `.left-bar` имеет `float: left;` и находиться до применения `clear: left`, `clear: left` опустилось ниже блока `.left-bar` (см. скрин).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странно, что разработчики сделали clear абсолютным. Вполне разумным было бы реализовать его локальным, действующим в своей области видимости...

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут говорят, что clear работает сразу на все уровни (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885721/css-how-to-clear-a-floating-object-only-one-level-not-the-all-the-way-to-the-l)

Почему бы не использовать флексбокс для лэйаута?

https://jsfiddle.net/k5z15sds/

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left-bar {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
}

.right-bar {
  flex: 1;
  height: 700px;
  background: #adc6e7;
}
```

Comment: Я  не уверен, что flex поддерживается всеми браузерами, включая мобильные. И, кроме того, почему же в моем случае элементы ведут себя подобным образом?

Comment: Я не спец по флоату. Видимо  флоат очищается незавимо от степени вложенности. (Так написано по той ссылке, по крайней мере). Проверить браузерную поддержку (я думаю вы и так знаете) можно здесь https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: для браузерной поддержки можно таблицей сверстать

Comment: Как сказал @DanielKhoroshko "флоат очищается независимо от степени вложенности" и запрещает обтекание. В вашем случаи высота, которая появляется, зависит от высоты элемента .left-bar, т.к. у него есть float: left.

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит из за контекста форматирования. Об этом почему-то не часто говорят, хотя знания о нем значительно уменьшит количество ошибок при верстке.

Блочный контекст форматирования может быть создан чем-либо из этого списка:

1. корневой элемент или что-то, что содержит его
2. плавающие элементы (элементы, у которых float не равно none)
3. абсолютно позиционированные элементы (элементы, значение  position которых либо absolute, либо fixed)
4. «строчные блоки» (элементы с display: inline-block)
5. И т.д.

Подробнее [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

Если хочется посмотреть в действие результат [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/p81pfoug/15/)

В примере у класс `wrap-box` раскомментируйте любую строчку

```
.wrap-box{
  //display: inline-block;
  //display: flow-root;
  //float: left;
  //overflow: auto;
  //overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#aacccc;
}
```